# javascript concat vs push benchmark

Tags: javascript, performance

There is this test on jsperf :
http://jsperf.com/javascript-array-concat-vs-push

It shows that concat is faster, but if you get that result in the initial array, without using a third variable, concat is much, much slower :

```
for (i = 10000; i > 0; i--) {
   arr1 = arr1.concat(arr2);
}
```

Even if you use a local var, but with the same name, the result is the same :

```
for (i = 10000; i > 0; i--) {
   var arr1 = arr1.concat(arr2);
}
```

Can someone explain this ?

Comment: Not sure I get the question, `concat` and `push` do different things, one joins two arrays, the other pushes to an array, but if you use some trickery with `apply` you can push all the values from one array to another array with a single line of code instead of iterations, but of course native methods are usually faster.

Comment: Firstly, you're changing the conditions of the initial performance test notably: the appended array is larger on each iteration. Aside from that, if you don't use a third variable, a helper variable is created and destroyed on each iteration which would explain additional performance drop.

Comment: Your two examples are equivalent. Javascript variables have function scope, not block scope, so the variable declaration is hoisted out of the loop.

Comment: @adeneo If you look at the jsperf he linked to, it does use "trickery with `apply`"

Comment: It looks to me like that jsperf is comparing apples and oranges. The `concat` test puts the result in a new variable, so it just concatenates the same two arrays multiple times. The `push` test is modifying one of the original arrays, so it keeps growing and growingon each iteration of the test. Your `concat` test is like that `push` test in the benchmark, because you're saving the result in `arr1`. That's why the performance is similar to the `push` benchmark.

Comment: @Barmar That's just it, it is not similar. If you modify the test and save the results in arr1 instead of arr3, concat is 99% slower. I guess Nit could be right with the helper variable, but I am not convinced.

Comment: That's what I'm saying. When you use the same variable, the array keeps growing, so it's slow just like the `push` test in the benchmark you linked to.

Answer (score 5):

You're mutating the original array in a loop.

```
for (i = 10000; i > 0; i--) {
   arr1 = arr1.concat(arr2);
}
```

Here the size of `arr1` keeps growing and as the array gets bigger it will get slower because it has to allocate more memory.

```
for (i = 10000; i > 0; i--) {
   var arr3 = arr1.concat(arr2);
}
```

Here you are assigning to a new variable without mutating `arr1` or `arr2` so your testing the performance of concatenating two small arrays.

In the `arr1` case your testing the performance of concatenating one large array with a small one.

Comment: You are missing the point. The question is about concat vs. push

Comment: It may be more insidious than this.  Because arr3 isn't used anywhere else, there is a really good chance that the optimizer has decided "Hey, why even concat?  The value is being thrown away anyways so let's just say we did this and terminate early".

Comment: No @ovi, the question may have been titled "concat versus push" but the actual question was "Can someone explain this ?"